# How to create a Map of different type of value in typescript

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-typings

I have started learning Typescript and I was trying to create a map with different type of values, but it's not working.
I tried directly giving `string` and `number` as an options while defining the `Map` but it's throwing error that we are unable to map `number` to `string`

```
const testMap: Map<string,string|number> = new Map([["a", "test1"],["b","test2"],["c",1]]);
```

Please suggest.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBFCm0CyBDADgLhqtAeaATgJZgDmANDISaTAD4xgCuAtgEbwEB8MAvI-ADu2dAAoA2uIBEKKZSkJoARikBdStLZyYCxFABMajVODalq1QEoA3EA)

Comment: The code you shared has a syntax error. Is this the same code you are using? Please share the exact error message and a [mre].

Comment: yes that was the issue i was facing @aleksey has suggested something and it worked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Typescript is not able to infer value type properly in this case, but you can specify [generic type parameters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-classes) explicitly when calling `Map`'s constructor:

```
const testMap = new Map<string, string | number>([["a", "test1"], ["b", "test2"], ["c", 1]]);
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBFCm0CyBDADjAvDM8DuMqaAPNAE4CWYA5gDQzlXUwA+OArgLYBG8ZAfAAoA2sIBEKMfTEJoARjEBdeuO5SYMxFABMSlWODq5ixQEoA3EA)

Comment: Thank you for explaining the issue and the solution as well, it worked